# Error while compiling eigen program: error: 'seq' is not a member of 'Eigen'

Tags: c++, eigen3

I am trying to index a matrix in indexes which follow an arithmetic sequence. According to the Eigen tutorial on the official website, I should use Eigen::seq(firstVal, lastVal, step) to generate this sequence. After calling this the error, as pasted in the title of this thread pops up.

I checked all the files of my local eigen folder, for the 'seq' method, but no luck. It wasn't anywhere. I guess this means that some file is missing, right?

Code goes smth like this.

**Headers at the top**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
```

```cpp
m1(row, Eigen::seq(some_index*m1.cols(), some_index*m1.cols() + m1.cols()-1, step))= m2.block(row, 0, 1, m2.cols());
```

where of course, m1.cols() >> m2.cols()

Error output:

```
error: 'seq' is not a member of 'Eigen'
```

The expected result would be to get the row from matrix m2 (where m2.cols() < m1.cols()) and assign the row's values to certain indexes in the same row number of m1.

Comment: Not an expert on Eigen, but looking at the repo, I think I found the function in https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/raw/537d95e06d30439429d0a8270bbde46340fd87b2/Eigen/src/Core/ArithmeticSequence.h . Do you have the file? Have you check the #define you have?

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts this is strange! This file that you have sent a link to, is not part of the git repo of eigen, but it is part of the bitbucket repo. As e result it is not part of my files as well. I will try to change my sources and will see if it works out!
Thanks!

Comment: It's part also of the github repo: https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/03a902ce645776d7e55f64f1d7f0d7eeab04e3c3/Eigen/src/Core/ArithmeticSequence.h , actually I found first the github repo, then I realized it was a mirror and I searched for the official repo. From which github repo did you get Eigen?

Comment: Oh snap! Yeah I used a third party mirror... Now I am getting some other errors, but I think this problem is solved, please comment below so that I can mark this thread as solved!

Comment: You mean that I should give an answer? Interestingly enough, though, the tar.gz available on the website do not provide the file.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts Yeah , apparently there are a ton of incorrect repos out there. I stumbled on some others with the same file missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After inspecting the official repo

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/

The required function is in the file `Eigen/src/core/ArithmeticSequence.h` which is included in the general header `Eigen/Core` already used in the snippet.

The issue seems to be that OP downloaded Eigen from a third-party repo not in sync with the main repo and the aforementioned file was missing.

I add this note for posterity: The latest stable release at the moment of writing is 3.3.7, released in 2018, (see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), and does not include the file. So, if anybody else finds the same issue, please try to clone the official repo.

Comment: Backporting changes to 3.3.x would be quite cumbersome in many cases -- and generally, the stable branch mostly gets bug-fixes, but no new features. But yes, it has been a while since a new version of Eigen was released ... (btw: The official repo is a mercurial not a git repo)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was having trouble using `Eigen::all`, which is pretty strange since I downloaded the `.zip` from [the official website link](http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3.7.zip) of the latest release 3.3.7. After cloning another version from Github as you suggested, I was able to use this `all` operator.

Comment: So there is no way to slice arrays using operator() in the latest stable release of Eigen?

Comment: omg! Thanks for the answer! could have caused a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 5):

The required function is in the file Eigen/src/core/ArithmeticSequence.h which is included in the general header `Eigen/Core`. So `#include "Eigen/Core"` will suffice. (As @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts pointed out).

However, to address the confusion in his answer: `ArithmeticSequences` such as `Seq` are planned for Eigen version *3.4.0* So they are not present in versions prior to this. When I write this, the latest official release is *3.3.9* which thus doesn't support `ArithmeticSequences`.

If you look in the [official repo](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen), you will find that the file is also not present for release *3.3.9* and earlier. Right now, it is only included in the `3.4.0-rc1` and `master` branch.

**So to answer your question:** You are most likely using an older version of Eigen and you will need to use `Eigen 3.4.0-rc1` or later.